# How to configure multicolumn header in sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am having a sharepoint list. I want to group the columns.

For a clear understanding of my requirement, please see the image below:

[image]

Is this possible in sharepoint list? I am using version 2010.

Comment: Do you want to create a custom list like this image ? OR a web part ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to render List View for [XSLTListViewWebPart (XLV)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806162%28v=office.14%29.aspx) with *custom columns header layout*  including the specified grouping. It is XSLT based solution that does not requires any custom coding.

This could be accomplished with SharePoint Designer, see for example [Create a custom list view using SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-view-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010379079.aspx?fromAR=3)

---

Below is described similar solution, but instead of modifying XSLT inside List View page,  we will create separate XSLT file for it.

### Steps

1. Create Custom View for List.
2. Create custom XSLT style sheet for rendering custom header layout in that view. Source code for this example is located [**here**](https://gist.github.com/4383069).
3. Save it for convenience in the same location where List pages are resides as shown on picture below [image]
4. Open Custom View page in SPD and specify in XLV properties XSLink property  as shown below on picture [image]
5. Save changes.

List with custom View is shown below

[image]